# Mutable Flatbuffers, Performance loss?

Tags: c++, c++11, protocol-buffers, game-engine, flatbuffers

How much of a performance loss is there to use flatbuffer mutable?

Is it "correct" use of flatbuffers to have a object/stuct which should be editable (ie game state)

In my example i have the following classes at the moment:

```
class Game:
    std::vector<Player>;
    int frames;

class Player:
    std::string name;
    int oil;
    std::vector<Unit>;

class Unit:
    int id;
    int hp
    ...
```

Would it be sensible to use a flatbuffer for each of these objects storing all information about each unit? Or would a mutable flatbuffer decrease performance?

If flatbuffers are wrong tool for this job, which technology should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FlatBuffers has very efficient in-place mutation of scalars, but mutating things like vectors in-place requires the use of reflection, which currently is slower and clumsier, thus not recommended for use as game state that is frequently modified.

Instead, in your case, I'd recommend using the object API (`--gen-object-api`) which gives you automatic conversion to/from a FlatBuffer and allows you convenient mutation with standard C++ types.

Comment: A little sideroad on the road to success; So, for some reason when i edit my object using the mutable accessors nothing really happens. The value is simply not changed/mutated.

Comment: Are you checking the return value? If it is false, it means it couldn't be changed because the field was not present (e.g. when equal to the default value). You can avoid this by creating the FlatBuffer using the force_defaults option in the builder.

Comment: Ok, so all fields must be initially set in in order for them to be mutable?

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid so. The fact that it doesn't store fields that are not set or default is a great space-saving feature, but it doesn't help with mutation :)

Comment: I'd like to say what Aardappel said above again, in different words. You can use scalars as mutable reliably. You just have to use force_defaults in the builder to ensure that a space is assigned even if what's set is a default value. So, a combination of default value + force_defaults works fine for reliable mutation of scalars.